# c++ passing function from a class to another class

Tags: c++, arduino

I have a main class and 2 different classes with .h and .cpp files(class1st and class2nd).

**main.cpp**

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "class1st.h"
#include "class2nd.h"

void printerOnMain();
class1st instOf1stClassOnMain(printerOnMain);
class2nd instOf2ndClassOnMainNo1(1);
class2nd instOf2ndClassOnMainNo2(2);
class2nd instOf2ndClassOnMainNo3(3);

void printerOnMain()
{
    Serial.println("Its OK.");
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(57600);
    instOf1stClassOnMain.showOn1stClass();
    instOf2ndClassOnMainNo1.checkOn2ndClass();
    instOf2ndClassOnMainNo2.checkOn2ndClass();
    instOf2ndClassOnMainNo3.checkOn2ndClass();
}

void loop() {

}
```

**class1st.h**

```
#ifndef __CLASS1ST_H__
#define __CLASS1ST_H__

class class1st
{
private:
public:
    class1st(void (*invokerFunc)());
    void (*invokerFunc)();
    void showOn1stClass();

}; //class1st

#endif //__CLASS1ST_H__
```

**class1st.cpp**

```
#include "class1st.h"

class1st::class1st(void (*invokerFunc)())
{
    this->invokerFunc = invokerFunc;
}

void class1st::showOn1stClass()
{
    invokerFunc();
}
```

**class2nd.h**

```
#ifndef __CLASS2ND_H__
#define __CLASS2ND_H__

#include <Arduino.h>
#include "class1st.h"

class class2nd
{
private:
    int __instNo;

public:
    class2nd(int instNo);
    void showOn2ndClass();
    void checkOn2ndClass();
    class1st instOf1stClassOn2ndClass(showOn2ndClass);

}; //class2nd

#endif //__CLASS2ND_H__
```

**class2nd.cpp**

```
#include "class2nd.h"

class2nd::class2nd(int instNo)
{
    __instNo = instNo;
}

void class2nd::showOn2ndClass()
{
    Serial.print("class2nd instance no: ");Serial.println(__instNo);
}

void class2nd::checkOn2ndClass()
{
    instOf1stClassOn2ndClass.showOn1stClass();
}
```

I'm sending the invoker function to class1st while creating its instances. The invoker function can be from any class, and any instance's of any class.

Here is working princible:

1. I have created and instance of class1st on main.cpp as **instOf1stClassOnMain(printerOnMain)** which sent an invoker function(printerOnMain() ) to class1st.
2. Now class1st know that, which function will be called when **showOn1stClass()** is called.
3. I called the **showOn1stClass()** from **main.cpp**
4. Bingo, it has worked and class1st show me the **printerOnMain** function.

So far everything is well.

But when I tried to do same thing on a different class rather than main, it didnt work.

Here is what I have tried (or say what I wanted to...)

1. I have created and instance of class1st on class2nd.h as **class1st instOf1stClassOn2ndClass(showOn2ndClass);** which sent an invoker function(showOn2ndClass() ) to class1st.
2. Now class1st know that, which function will be called when **showOn1stClass()** is called from class2nd.
3. I have created the instances of class2nd on main class.
4. What does this mean, any instances of class2nd will use the **showOn2ndClass** function, when it needed. But they are independent to each other.
5. I tried to call the **checkOn2ndClass** function on main class with the instances of class2nd
6. Boommm. It didnt work and told me that " **'showOn1stClass' is not a type** "

   Hope to explain clearly....

Comment: The compiler sees `class1st instOf1stClassOn2ndClass(showOn2ndClass);` as a function declaration.

Comment: I have problems to read your code, imho your class and instance names are rather confusing, but I think one problem is that `void (*invokerFunc)()` is pointer to a free function and `showOn2ndClass` is a member function. Member function pointers are fundamentlly different from free function pointers, you need an instance to call them. Please include a [mcve] of the non working code and the error message

Comment: You need something akin to an interface in java.  You can create a base class that any of those classes can derive from. That way when you pass it around as that base class and then there’s only one type of function pointer to deal with.  See how printable works in the Arduino core to let you print a value from any type of class with the print class.  You inherit Printable and implement printTo and then your class type can go directly into a print statement.  (I may have botched the name of that class.  I think it’s Printable.  Someone will correct if I’m wrong.